# How to use multithreading in a looped function in julia

Tags: dataframe, multithreading, multiprocessing, julia

I have a big dataset and a function. The function looks like this:

```
function myfunc(df)
    iter = size(df)[1]
    v1 = Vector{Int64}()
    v2 = Vector{Int64}()
    v3 = Vector{Int64}()
    v4 = Vector{Int64}()
    v5 = Vector{Int64}()
    v6 = Vector{Int64}()
    v7 = Vector{Float64}()
    v8 = Vector{Int64}()
    v9 = Vector{Int64}()
    v10 = Vector{Int64}()
    v11 = Vector{Int64}()
    v12 = Vector{Int64}()
    v13 = Vector{Int64}()
    v14 = Vector{String}()
    v15 = Vector{String}()
    v16 = Vector{Int64}()
    v17 = Vector{Int64}()
    v18 = Vector{Int64}()
    v19 = Vector{Int64}()
    v20 = Vector{String}()
    v21 = Vector{String}()
       for i in 1:iter, j in (i+1):iter
            if (df[i,:][1] != df[j,:][1])  # not the same person
                if (((df[j,:]["StartTime"] < df[i,:]["EndTime"] < df[j,:]["EndTime"]) && (df[i,:]["StartTime"] <= df[j,:]["StartTime"])) || ((df[j,:]["StartTime"] < df[i,:]["StartTime"] < df[j,:]["EndTime"]) && (df[j,:]["EndTime"] < df[i,:]["EndTime"])) || ((df[j,:]["StartTime"] <= df[i,:]["StartTime"]) && (df[i,:]["EndTime"] <= df[j,:]["EndTime"])) || ((df[i,:]["StartTime"] < df[j,:]["StartTime"]) && (df[j,:]["EndTime"] <= df[i,:]["EndTime"])))
                    l = euclidean([df[i,:]["X"], df[i,:]["Y"]], [df[j,:]["X"], df[j,:]["Y"]]) 
                        if l <=50     
                            push!(v1, df[i,:]["Person"])
                            push!(v2, df[j,:]["Person"])
                            push!(v3, df[i,:]["StartTime"])
                            push!(v4, df[i,:]["EndTime"])
                            push!(v5, df[j,:]["StartTime"])
                            push!(v6, df[j,:]["EndTime"])
                            push!(v7, round(l, sigdigits = 3))
                            push!(v8, df[i,:]["X"])
                            push!(v9, df[i,:]["Y"])
                            push!(v10, df[j,:]["X"])
                            push!(v11, df[j,:]["Y"])
                            push!(v12, df[i,:]["Link"])
                            push!(v13, df[j,:]["Link"])
                            push!(v14, df[i,:]["ActType"])
                            push!(v15, df[j,:]["ActType"])
                            push!(v16, df[i,:]["groupindices"])
                            push!(v17, df[j,:]["groupindices"])
                            push!(v18, df[i,:]["income"])
                            push!(v19, df[j,:]["income"])
                            push!(v20, df[i,:]["home-activity-zone"])
                            push!(v21, df[j,:]["home-activity-zone"])
                            i += 1
                            j += 1   
                        end
                    end
                end
            end
return DataFrame(Person1 = Person1, Person2 = Person2, Distance = Distance, 
Stime1 = Stime1, Etime1 = Etime1, Stime2 = Stime2, Etime2 = Etime2, 
X1 = X1, Y1 = Y1, X2 = X2, Y2 = Y2, Link1 = Link1, Link2 = Link2, 
Acttype1 = Acttype1, Acttype2 = Acttype2, Groupindices1 = Groupindices1, Groupindices2 = Groupindices2, 
Income1 = Income1, Income2 = Income2, haz1 = haz1, haz2 = haz2)
end
```

The running time to get the results will be more than 10 days, so I want to use the multi-computing method to get the results. I tried the multi-threading which threw an error "nested outer loops are not currently supported by @threads". I have read some tutorials but did not find a method running the program using multi-computing. I want to know some suggestions.

Comment: Just two points. Instead of pushing 20 times just make an output df and push to it a. ew row when needed. Also, why do you increase the 2 indexes i and j? They increase aytomatically at each iteration of the loop..

Comment: Thank you. Because I am a beginner at programming...

Answer (score 1):

The direct answer to your question is that you can't do

```
@threads for i in 1:iter, j in (i+1):iter
```

so the easiest thing to do is to thread only one dimension, e.g.

```
@threads for i in 1:iter
    for j in (i+1):iter
```

The better answer is probably that your code looks very inefficient, and I'm not sure whether it's thread safe either so your time is probably better spent coming up with a more efficient way of solving your problem rather than trying to throw compute at it.

I'd recommend making a runnable example with some dummy data and ask for help to speed things up on the JuliaLang Discourse forum.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can do triangular iteration with `@threads`. Are you thinking of `@turbo`?

Comment: No, I meant what I wrote although maybe my information is out of date (I haven't written threaded code since at least 1.7 I think). On 1.10-beta2: `julia> Threads.@threads for i ∈ 1:10, j ∈ 1:10
           println(i, j)
       end
ERROR: LoadError: ArgumentError: nested outer loops are not currently supported by @threads`

Comment: I believe that's just a syntax issue. Try `Threads.@threads for i ∈ 1:10  for j ∈ 1:10 
 println(i, j)  end  end`

Comment: This discussion isn't ideal in the comments I guess :) - it seems to me that what you just posted is what I said in my answer? I.e. you can't do `@threads for i ∈ 1:5, for j ∈ 1:3; something(); end` but you can do `@threads for i ∈ 1:5; for j ∈ 1:3; println(i, j); end; end`.

Comment: I don't think it's the same. You indicated that one must multi-thread the _inner_ loop (by your suggested solution, plus the remark "thread only one dimension"). I think it's important to clarify that there's no problem with threading nested loops, but that just the special syntax `@threads for i in 1:n, j in 1:m` is unsupported. In fact, I think the error message itself is confusing, and borderline misleading.

Comment: Okay, I see your point - I did not mean to suggest that one has to thread the inner dimension, simply (as I said) one dimension - your point below that one generally threads the outermost dimension is well taken, but apart from which line of the (then multi-line) nested for loop the `@threads` appears our answers are the same.

Comment: Okay, but I definitely mistook your answer to mean that nested loops could not be threaded, only inner loops (then presumably others could misunderstand as well). And since this was specifically tied to the special loop syntax, I thought it well worth clarifying.

Comment: To out it another way: your solution changed the *meaning* of the code, while in fact the only necessary change was surface syntax.

Comment: If you assume that the original meant threading over `i`, but as you say in your answer it's not clear what the original code means (hence the error). But as I said your point that the outer dimension is probably the best "default" assumption I've editet my answer so that people stumbling on this will try the outer loop first.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is that the `@threads` macro is not able to handle 'nested loop syntax', meaning that

```
@threads for i in 1:iter, j in (i+1):iter
```

will fail. This does *not* mean, however, that you cannot multi-thread nested loops, you just need to write them like this:

```
@threads for i in 1:iter
    for j in (i+1):iter
```

You are right to try to multi-thread the outer loop, it is normally preferred to try to parallelize at the highest level.

I'm not sure exactly why this limitation exists, it's probably just a bit difficult to parse that particular syntax.

Unfortunately, this will not solve your performance issues, since multi-threading scales very poorly when each thread allocates a lot of memory. You should first optimize the single-threaded performance of your code, focusing specifically on reducing memory allocations.

You can do this by pre-allocating the arrays you need instead of repeatedly `push!`ing, and avoid slicing. I am not familiar with DataFrames, but I assume that things like this:

```
if (df[i,:][1] != df[j,:][1])
```

is extremely inefficient. Is it not possible to write something like

```
if (df[i,1] != df[j,1])
```

instead?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I changed the script accordingly and tested it from the small dataset, like df_100, df_1000, ..... When it reached to df_100000, there is the error: ERROR: DimensionMismatch: column :Person1 has length 26424 and column :Distance has length 26422. I think it is due to the data racing (? ). Trying to work it out.